# .htaccess directory-to-file redirect not working with forward slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a basic redirect in a .htacess file, from a directory URL to a file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/mydirectory/(.*)$ myfile.php?q=$2
```

It is not working. The problem is I can't get it to work unless I do:

```
RewriteRule (.*)mydirectory(.*)$ myfile.php?q=$2
```

in which case the captured string ($2) is "mydirectory" (?!), and of course the rule would apply to any URL containing "mydirectory" as a substring, even if it's not between slashes, which is no good.

The test URL is:

```
http://localhost/base/mydirectory/some-other-string
```

What I expect is:

```
http://localhost/base/myfile.php?q=some-other-string"
```

What I get with the first rule is nothing (rule does not apply/not working), and "myfile.php?q=base/mydirectory" with the second rule, respectively.

The same happens if I use RewriteCond: as soon as I add the **damned forward slashes**, the rule does not apply anymore. I even escaped the forward slashes, although there's no need for that, to no avail.

I'm not a mod_rewrite expert, but I'm no stranger to it. IMO, the first rule should work, but it doesn't. I'm probably doing something horribly wrong, but I'm too close to see it.

Please take a look, it's driving me nuts.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Slashes have special meanings in regular expressions you need to escape them:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/mydirectory\/(.*)$ myfile.php?q=$2
```